# Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid |z|<1\}$ and let $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then which of the followings are true

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}$ and let $f_n:D\to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$ Then which of the followings are true.

1. The sequences $\{f_n(z)\}$ and $\{f_n'(z)\}$ converge uniformly on $D$
2. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converge uniformly on $D$
3. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'$ converge  for each $z\in D$
4. The sequence $\{f_n''(z)\}$ does not converge  unless $z=0$

How should i solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe I make a stupid mistake, but $f_n'=f_{n-1}$, right? If so, then in this question there is only one sequence of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {z^n\over n}$. Then $1\over R$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|{{n+1}\over n}|=1\implies R=1.$ The radius of convergences of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'$ is thus also $1$ $\implies$ **$3$ is correct** & **$1,2,4$ are false**.