# Checking convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with the following question.

> Let $D=\{z\in C:|z|<1\}$ and let $f_n:D\to C$ be defined by $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,...$ Then which of the following is true?
>
> a) the sequences $\{f_n(z)\}$ and ${f'_n(z)}$ converge uniformly on $D$
>
> b) the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on $D$
>
> c) the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'_n(z)$ converges for each $z\in D$
>
> d) the sequence $\{f''_n(z)\}$ does not converge unless $z=0$

My attempt: $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$, so, $f'_n(z)=z^{n-1}$, and this series would converge for all $z\in D$. So, $3rd$ option is correct.

And $f''_n(z)=(n-1)z^{n-2}$, which again I think would converge for all $z\in D$ and not just for $z=0$. So, $4th$ option is false.

And $f_n(0)=0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(z)=0$, ${f_n(z)}$ is uniformly convergent. And $z^{n-1}=0$ for $z=0$ or when $n$ is very large. So, ${f'_n(z)}$ is uniformly convergent. So, $1st$ is also true. But as per the answer key, only $3rd$ option is correct.

And regarding $2nd$ option, I am totally undecided.

I am aware that this question has already been discussed at the following link, but it doesn't satisfy my concern.

[Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid |z|<1\}$ and let $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then which of the followings are true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262516/let-d-z-in-mathbb-c-mid-z1-and-let-f-nz-fracznn-for-n-1-2)

Comment: can anyone pls tell how to make hyperlinks to my text. I didn't want to paste the whole link here. I just wanted to refer the link.

Comment: The convergence of $f_n'$ is not _uniform_ on all of $D$.

Comment: I wish you could tell where it is not uniform.

Comment: Near the boundary. You have $\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert \to 1} \lvert f_n'(z)\rvert = 1$ for all $n$. The convergence is uniform on all $D_r = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\}$ for $r < 1$, but not on all of $D$.

Comment: But D doesn't include z=1. And on calculator, $0.9^{1000}$ is very close to zero and not 1. so i would say $\lim_{z\to 1}f'_n(z)=0$ for large n. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: But try $0.99999^{1000}$. That will be close to 1 (about $0.99$). You can get arbitrarily close to $1$, and that gives values arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: yes, that's perfect. thankyou very much.

Comment: And $\{f_n(z)\}$ is uniformly convergent, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, $\lvert f_n(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac1n$ on $D$.

Answer (score 1):

For option (2), which apparently is the last one you need to work. we have

$$\left|\frac{z^n}n\right|\le |z|^n\implies\;\;\text{we've uniform convergence of the series for}\;\;|z|\le r<1$$

by Weierstrass M-Test, yet near the boundary we've a problem similar to the one mentioned by Daniel in his comment, since in the limit when $\;z\to 1^-\;$ we get the harmonic series which, of course, is divergent.