# A sequence of complex functions on open unit disc

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let $D=\mathbb\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z| \lt 1\}$ and let $f_n:D\to \mathbb{C}$ be given by $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}n $ for $n=1,2,3,,,$ . Then

$(1)$ The sequence $\{f_n(z)\}$ and $\{f_n'(z)\}$ converge uniformly on $D$.

$(2)$ The sereis $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on $ D$.

$(3)$ The sereis $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n'(z)$ converges for each $z\in D$.

$(4)$ The sequence $\{f_n''(z)\}$ does not converge unless $z=0$

I know that this is already asked here ([Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb C\mid |z|<1\}$ and let $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then which of the followings are true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/262516/710290)) but my purpose here is to understand why the other options are incorrect.

My attempt:

I know that option $(3)$ is true .So I will just focus on options $(1),(2),(4)$.

For option $(1)$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitary .For $|z| \lt 1$, we have

$|f_n(z)|=\frac{|z|^n}{n} \lt \frac 1n \lt \epsilon $ for $n\gt \big[\frac 1{\epsilon}\big] $

This shows $f_n(z)\to 0$ uniformly on $D$.

Again $f_n'(z)=z^{n-1}$ .

Clearly  $f_n'(z)\to 0$ pointwise  on $D$

Now $|f_n'(z) | \lt \epsilon $ to hold,    we must have

$n\gt \big[\frac{ log (\epsilon) }{log(|z|)}\big]+1$, which shows that $n$ depends on $z$  and hence $\{f_n'(z)\}$ does not converge uniformly on $D$

So option $(1)$ is false .I would like any sequential argument here .

For option $(4)$

$f''_n(z)=(n-1)z^{n-2}$

Then $|f''_n(z)|=|(n-2+1)z^{n-2}| \le |(n-2)z^{n-2}|+|z^{n-2}|\to 0$

as $n\to \infty$

So $(4)$ is false .

Are my works correct. I couldn't prove $(2)$ false. Please help with that.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are correct. For showing that $f_n'$ does not converge uniformly you can also use the fact that $f_n'(1-\frac 1 n) \to \frac 1 e \neq 0$

Hint for 2): If $\sum f_n(z)$ converges uniformly then $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}\frac {z^{k}} k$ tends to $0$ uniformly  as $m >n \to \infty$. This implies that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}\frac {(1-\frac 1  m)^{k}} k \to 0$. Note that $1-\frac 1  m \geq 1-\frac 1  k$. So $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}\frac {(1-\frac 1  k)^{k}} k \to 0$. Can you get a contradiction from this?

Comment: Sorry sir, didn't get enough time to see your answer properly. Is this the contradiction you are talking about? We know $\lim_{n\to \infty} \big(1-1/n \big)^n=1/e $ .Thus $\exists M\in  \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\gt M$, we have $\big(1-1/n \big)^n \gt \frac 1{2e} $ implying $\frac{\big(1-1/k \big)^k}{k} \gt \frac 1{2ek}$ for $k\gt M$ which makes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\big(1-1/n \big)^n}{n} $ divergent thus contradicting $\sum_{k=n}^m \frac{\big(1-1/k \big)^k}{k} \to 0 $ as $n\to \infty$ .

Comment: Please confirm if I am correct or not.

Comment: @user710290 Yes, your argument is exactly what  I had in mind.